# Android - Missing File Error while foursquare image upload on checkin

Tags: android, foursquare

While uploading the image on the foursquare with httpPost the following error is generating in response:

> {"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"Missing file
>   upload"},"response":{}}

Here is the code below:

```
      Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("venueId", "5177a5b8e4b0de6e7df647b4"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkinId",name));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add?v=20130726&oauth_token="+ActivityWebView.accessToken);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
            "image/jpeg");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   long i= response.getEntity().getContentLength();
  String res=  inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
  Log.v("response", ""+res);
  System.out.println("resssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"+res);
  System.out.println("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"+i);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"response"+res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
```

This might be due to the error while uploading the image.

Comment: have you got any solution?